# XML to JSON Liquid fails in Logic APP on special Characters

Tags: json, xml, liquid, azure-logic-apps

[image]

Logic App received a XML response message.
This message is transformed from XML to JSON with a liquid template,but when special characters are in the XML response the Liquid fails...

- XML input file (browser display)

```
<ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
 <item>
  <KUNNR>xxx</KUNNR>
  <NAME1>Strandshop "Allaart"</NAME1>
 </item>
</ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
```

```
XML encoded data
            <ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
                <item>
                    <KUNNR>xx</KUNNR>
                    <NAME1>Strandshop &#34;Allaart&#34;</NAME1>
                </item>
            </ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
            <ET_RETURN/>
```

Liquid
`"AfnemerNaam": "{{item.AfnemerNaam}}"`

Liquid Error in Logic App...
IncorrectLiquidTransformOutputType.

I have tried using single quotes

Liquid
`"AfnemerNaam": '{{item.AfnemerNaam}}'`

This works for the above issue but it fails on the bellow situation

XML input bowser display

```
<ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
 <item>
  <KUNNR>0000071719</KUNNR>
  <NAME1>*STK*Camping 't Strandheem</NAME1>
 </item>
</ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
```

```
<ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
                <item>
                    <KUNNR>Y</KUNNR>
                    <NAME1>*STK*Camping &#39;t Strandheem</NAME1>
                </item>
            </ET_KLANTEN_ALL>
```

Could use some advise on this....

Required output in JSON

```
{
    "Afnemers": [
       
        {
            "AfnemerNummer": "0000036082",
            "AfnemerNaam": "Strandshop \"Allaart\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Afnemers": [
        {
            "AfnemerNummer": "0000071719",
            "AfnemerNaam": "*STK*Camping 't Strandheem"

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want the json to look like because you don’t need liquid to convert the xml to json.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the required JSON output to the message. What do you suggest to generate the XML to JSON conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion but if you want to avoid using liquid, you can perform a simple conversion to JSON using an expression and then loop through the result and convert it to your new structure with the loop.

[image: Top]

Using the above, I loaded your XML (with the two items) into a string variable and then in the next step, used a `Parse json` step to turn it into an intermediary JSON structure that preserves the special characters, etc. like you want.

The expression above is ...

```
json(xml(variables('XML')))
```

The schema of your `Parse json` step (to make it easier for you) is ...

```
{
    "properties": {
        "ET_KLANTEN_ALL": {
            "properties": {
                "item": {
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "KUNNR": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "NAME1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "KUNNR",
                            "NAME1"
                        ],
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

That will create this JSON ...

```
{
  "ET_KLANTEN_ALL": {
    "item": [
      {
        "KUNNR": "0000071719",
        "NAME1": "*STK*Camping 't Strandheem"
      },
      {
        "KUNNR": "xxx",
        "NAME1": "Strandshop \"Allaart\""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then all you need to do is loop through each item and append it to an array variable ...

[image: Bottom Flow]

... and finalise the result.

[image: Set Result]

This is the end game ...!

[image: End game]

This is the json definition of my answer if you want to load it into your own tenant.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_Result": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Afnemers",
                            "value": {
                                "AfnemerNaam": "@{items('For_each')?['NAME1']}",
                                "AfnemerNummer": "@{items('For_each')?['KUNNR']}"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['ET_KLANTEN_ALL']?['item']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Afnemers",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Result": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Result": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result",
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_XML": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "XML",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "<ET_KLANTEN_ALL>\n <item>\n  <KUNNR>0000071719</KUNNR>\n  <NAME1>*STK*Camping 't Strandheem</NAME1>\n </item>\n <item>\n  <KUNNR>xxx</KUNNR>\n  <NAME1>Strandshop \"Allaart\"</NAME1>\n </item>\n</ET_KLANTEN_ALL>"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@json(xml(variables('XML')))",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ET_KLANTEN_ALL": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "item": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "KUNNR": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "NAME1": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "KUNNR",
                                                "NAME1"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_XML": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Set_Result": {
                "inputs": {
                    "name": "Result",
                    "value": {
                        "Afnemers": "@variables('Afnemers')"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "SetVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have managed it using liquid.
Please note solution to present "text" correct in the JSON use a single quote.
In all other situations use the double quote.

```
 {% if item.AfnemerNaam contains '"' %}

      "AfnemerNaam": '{{item.AfnemerNaam}}'

 {% else %}

      "AfnemerNaam": "{{item.AfnemerNaam}}"

 {% endif %},
```